Visualize $\mathbb {RP} ^ 2 \# \mathbb {RP} ^ 2 \# \mathbb {RP} ^ 2 \# \mathbb {RP} ^ 2$ as an immersed surface in $\mathbb R ^ 3$
I have a short question about Munkres chapter 74 question 4 part (b).

(b) Show how to picture the $4$-fold projective plane as an immersed surface in $\mathbb R ^ 3$.

In the previous part of the question, we just showed how it was possible to write that $\mathbb{RP}^2 \# \mathbb{RP}^2 \simeq K$, so I believe that we may visualize the $4$-fold connected sum by appealing to associativity.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb {RP} ^ 2 \# \mathbb {RP} ^ 2 \# \mathbb {RP} ^ 2 \# \mathbb {RP} ^ 2 &= \left(\mathbb {RP} ^ 2 \# \mathbb {RP} ^ 2\right) \# \left(\mathbb {RP} ^ 2 \# \mathbb {RP} ^ 2\right) \\
&\simeq K^2 \# K^2
\end{align}
$$
Mentally, I envisage the shape by creating two Klein bottles, deleting a small circular neighborhood from both, and connecting the rims bounding these new holes with a tube. Is the the right idea? I am of the mindset that this question is either extremely easy or very difficult. I want to make sure that I have not overlooked something obvious.
Thank you

Yes, this is the right approach.
